# How to calculate jqGrid header height

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

jqgrid header

may contain extra toolbar defined using

```
toolbar: [true, "top"],
```

contains navigation toolbar defined using

```
$grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#grid_toppager', {...
```

and contains search toolbar.

To resize grid to end of screen I'm looking for a way to calculate this header height
in window resize.
I tried code below but this sets grid height too big.
How to calculate grid header height ?

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
  var extraToolbarHeight = $('#t_' + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id)).outerHeight(true),
       caption_height=$("div#gview_"+$grid[0].id+" > div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").outerHeight(true);
  $('#grid1container').height($(window).height() - 18);
  $grid.jqGrid('setGridHeight', $('#grid1container').height()-caption_height
        -extraToolbarHeight );
     });


    <div id="grid1container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <table id="grid">
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Didn't run your code, but have you tried replacing outerHeight with innerHeight?

Comment: I replaced heights with innerHeight() but problem persists. top of grid is moved out of screen. Bottom of grid ends in browser window properly. Replacing caption_height with hard coded value creates with height exactly of browser height. However this value depends on search toolbar height and thus cannot hard-coded, should determined dynamically. How to find search toolbar height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function I wrote to resize my jqGrids to fit their container element. See if it fits your needs.

```
// resize a grid to fill the space of its container
// this will throw an error if you pass in a non-existant
// Parameters:
//  grid - a reference to your grid
//  container - a reference to your container, or the selector
// Usage:
// resizeGrid($('#gridXYZ'), '#largeGridDiv')
function resizeGrid(grid, container) {
    if (typeof container == 'string') {
        container = $(container);
    }
    if (container.length > 0) {
        var headerHeight = $($('.ui-jqgrid-hdiv')[0]).height();
        var newHeight = container.height() - headerHeight;
        grid.jqGrid().setGridHeight(newHeight);
        grid.jqGrid().setGridWidth(container.width());
    } else {
        throw ('Non-existant container passed to resizeGrid()');
    }
}


// some other selectors that may help, again grid 
var gviewSelector = '#gview_' + $('#gridXYZ').attr('id');
var headerSelector = gviewSelector + ' .ui-jqgrid-hdiv';
var bodySelector = gviewSelector + ' .ui-jqgrid-bdiv';
```

Comment: This set too big height: search toolbar contains jqGrid datapicker button. In this case search toolbar wraps into two lines and this method returns too small height. Also it does not count additional toolbar height which may added to jqgrid.

Comment: I used Chrome's DOM Inspector (press F12) to figure out the selectors  to get the header's height. You should be able to do the same thing to get the selector to find the toolbar's height, and then adjust the calculation for newHeight accordingly.

Comment: I read Oleg docs about jqGrid header element and selectors seems to be correct. No idea whan causes this. Maybe it is is related to searh toolbar wrapping into multiple lines and setGridHeight() setting invalid height